# CopySystemProxySettings Equivalent in Monotouch

Tags: http, xamarin.ios, webproxy, mt

What's the equivalent api to copy phone's system settings to my app in Monotouch?
can i use webproxy instead? how to do that? can the monotouch team give some example?

Thank you.